# Set Session Timeout to a specific time instead of length?

Tags: asp.net, session, iis

Is there any way to have sessions timeout at a specific time, such as 5pm? So if someone starts a session at 7am and another starts at 4pm, they both timeout at 5pm. I would like my users to stay logged in until the work day ends, regardless of the time their session started.

Comment: You'd better use session service or SQL Server session mode, and then intentionally break them at 5pm. That's much simpler than hacking the built-in session timeout mechanism which is not customizable in the way you wanted.

Comment: It is difficult to set  it in IIS, what you can set in IIS is the length of timeout or the state. As lexli saied, choose SQL Server state can store session data in a SQL server database, enabling that users stay logged. At 5pm, you can stop application pool or application to make user log out and session timeout. Then restart application pool or application next day.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configuring-step-2-configure-asp-net-settings#store-session-state-by-using-sql-server